# Filter jeasyui combo box inside Datagrid and show text and not values

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, jquery-ui

I am using a jquery easy ui crud datagrid and need a combo box for one of the columns. I have got the combo box populated but now I need to be able to filter the box if an item needs changing.

Part 2 of my question is that i have been unable to set the value in combo from the id to the actual text in the box eg. ID is 15488 which is Linkin Park. I want it to show Linkin Park, not the ID

The source data for the combo box is a php script selecting all of the artists and putting it in an array and then encoding it into json

Heres my code for the datagrid

```
<table id="dg" title="Tracklisting" style="width:1000px;height:250px"
        toolbar="#toolbar" pagination="true"
        rownumbers="true"  singleSelect="true">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th field="TRACK NO" width="50" editor="{type:'validatebox',options:{required:true}}">ID</th>
            <th field="DISC NO" width="50" editor="{type:'validatebox',options:{required:true}}">CAT No</th>
            <th field="TRACKTITLE" width="50" editor="{type:'validatebox',options:{required:true}}">Track No</th>
            <th field="VERSION" width="50" editor="text">Title</th>
            <th field="ARTIST_ID_1" width="100"  editor="{type:'combobox',options:
{valueField:'ID',textField:'ARTIST',url:'get_artist.php',required:true}}">Artist</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

Comment: Your code for the combo looks correct to me (I'm still studying the jeasyui thing though)  Could it be an issue with your PHP file?

Answer (score 0):

Answer to your second question :

`formatter="JS_function"`

Using this javascript function will be called to display text for the value selected in your grid.
Kindly explain 1st question in detail.